# Match login info from a list to txt values

Tags: c#

I have a list where I have stored two input values for valid logins (email, password), now I'm trying to look up the list and match this values to the user input before validating the login.

```
private List<User> users = new List<User>()
{
    new User(){Email = "Tera@gmail.com", Password = "p@ssword"},
    new User(){Email = "Mega@email.com", Password = "password"},
};
```

I have been trying a few things but cant get the right syntax. If I store this in two different lists I can make it work, just having trouble matching both values within the same list. Is there an efficient way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what have you tried so far? What is not working?

Comment: plain-text passwords FTL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the User Object from the List that matches your inputs, you could do this:

```
// foundUser is null if not found
User foundUser = users.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Email.Equals(inputEmail, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && i.Password.Equals(inputPassword));
```

If you just want to know weither a user exists or not, do this:

```
bool userExists = users.Any(i => i.Email.Equals(inputEmail, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && i.Password.Equals(inputPassword));
```

I also feel obligated to tell you that storing plain text passwords in a List, might not be the best approach security-wise.

Comment: Hey thanks, yea this worked perfectly, also I'm storing it in a list for school purposes, is just meant to be a small sample. Ill mark it as the answer in 5 mins

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to match the users input I would do the following:

```
    public static bool ValidateLogin(string email, string password)
    {
        return users.Any(x => x.Email.Equals(email) && x.Password.Equals(password));
    }
    private static List<User> users = new List<User>()
    {
        new User(){Email = "Tera@gmail.com", Password = "p@ssword"},
        new User(){Email = "Mega@email.com", Password = "password"},
    };
```

Comment: `return users.Any(x => x.Email.Equals(email) && x.Password.Equals(password)) ? true : false;` should just be `return users.Any(x => x.Email.Equals(email) && x.Password.Equals(password));` for simplicity.

Comment: Good point, I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
static class AuthEngine {
     private static List<User> users;

     public static bool Validate(string email, string password) 
     {
        var matchedUser = users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == email && x.Password == password);
        return matchedUser != null;
     }   
}
```

Do not forget to populate the list of users

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
users.Where(x => x.Email == email && x.Password == password).FirstOrDefault();
```

`email` and `password` being your inputs to search by.

It's also advisable to only store hashes of passwords, but that's not what you were asking.